# I'd like Fiware-Orion to automatically generate the entity ID

Tags: fiware-orion

How can I create entities in Fiware-Orion for anonymous reports submitted by multiple smartphones, where I have no control over the entity ID? I'd like Fiware-Orion to automatically generate the entity ID, but I'm facing issues with it not working as expected.

The version of Fiware-Orion I'm using is 3.7.0, and it's running with the following details:

```
Uptime: 2 days, 7 hours, 13 minutes, 24 seconds
Git Hash: 8b19705a8ec645ba1452cb97847a5615f0b2d3ca
Compile Time: Thu May 26 11:45:49 UTC 2022
Compiled By: root
Compiled In: 025d96e1419a
Release Date: Thu May 26 11:45:49 UTC 2022
Machine: x86_64
Documentation: Fiware-Orion Documentation
Library Versions:
    boost: 1_74
    libcurl: libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3
    libmosquitto: 2.0.12
    libmicrohttpd: 0.9.70
    openssl: 1.1
    rapidjson: 1.1.0
    mongoc: 1.17.4
    bson: 1.17.4
```

```
POST
{
  "type": "Complaint",
  "description": "Short description of the complaint",
  
  "creationDate": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2023-07-26T12:34:56.789Z"
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "geo:json",
    "value": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-46.73004, -23.55469]
    }
  },
  "image": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh", 
  "deviceId": "012edf4",
  "autoAssignId": true 
}
```

returns:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "entity id length: 0, min length supported: 1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple workaround is to generate the entity ID at client side. If you don't need a particular ID, you can generate it randomly.